# HTACCESS works local not on server

Tags: php, .htaccess, web, server, localhost

my code is working fine in localhost but when I upload it to the domain gives me Error 500 and sometimes blank page 
any suggestions please!
my htaccess:

```
enter code here
```

RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond $1 !^(index.php|images|robots.txt)

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]

Comment: Check what the error log has to say - that is always the first thing to do, when you encounter a 500 Internal Server Error.

Answer (score 0):

make sure that enabled the RewriteEngine in your apache configuration
i think this link will help to solve your problem https://hostadvice.com/how-to/how-to-enable-apache-mod_rewrite-on-an-ubuntu-18-04-vps-or-dedicated-server/

Comment: I checked it's enabled :(
any other solutions pls?
thanks

Comment: ok please check if you web-server is under apache or nginx , 
ok can you please follow this tutorial and tell me if it works 
https://mediatemple.net/community/products/dv/204643270/using-.htaccess-rewrite-rules